# ListenableWorker has no network when user not using application

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I have an application that is using a ListenableWorker to do periodic network synchronization. I have a broadcast receiver for 'on boot'.  The work is queued via enqueueUniquePeriodicWork. This all works fine when the user is inside my application.  But as soon as they exit, the Worker has no network. The worker gets executed by WorkManager but the getNetwork function returns null and any attempt to use the network fails.

This seems wrong to me.  If this is expected behavior, I'm not sure what the point of this feature is. If so I would need to got to a foreground service which I was hoping to avoid.

Am I missing something?

Edit:  I am using ListenableWorker as I am doing async network transactions.  I also added constraints.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED) to the job which I expected would prevent the job from being executed if there was no network at all. The end result was the job is still executed without network. Also getNetwork  always returns null whether a network is available or not so it isn't a good test of whether network transactions will work. Bottom line, when a user isn't using my app, the ListenableWorker can not use the network.

Comment: is the results tthe same with `Worker`?

Comment: Updated with some details.  I have not tried Worker as I am doing async network transactions.

Comment: Have you added a network constraint to your work request?

Comment: Yeah I said in the post I put a setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED) on the work. But that has no point pro or con. It doesn't prevent the job from running when network calls will fail, nor help them succeed.

Comment: Problem was easily reproducible and the network failures went away as soon as the workmanager work was executed in a foreground service.